# What broke? Site looks very different in IE vs Firefox/Safari

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

was working perfectly earlier this week, and now in IE everything seems to be messed up. Any ideas?

Specifically testing in IE 7/8

Comment: There are currently four versions of IE in circulation. Which one(s) do you mean? **Edit:** Ah I see, all of them :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the comment on your first line. IE looks for the doctype there and, if there is none, goes into quirks mode. Remove that comment.

btw, you are using the XHTML 1.1 doctype which is an XML application but serving it as HTML. If you must use XHTML, change it to the 1.0 doctype. Not that it makes any difference since you aren't serving XHTML anyway.

Answer (score 3):

There's a stylesheet (http://www.currensee.com/css/blueprint/ie.css) being served to all versions of IE less than IE8 that's returning a 404. I'd bet that might be your culprit.

This line of code:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

is using a relative path from your page.

Looks like it should be pointing at:

```
<!--[if lt IE 8]><link rel="stylesheet" href="/themes/currensee/css/blueprint/ie.css" type="text/css" media="screen, projection"><![endif]-->
```

where the rest of your stylesheets live.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether it's the root of your problem, but your IE stylesheet

```
http://www.currensee.com/css/blueprint/ie.css
```

doesn't exist.